# Splitting / chunking JSON files with JQ in Bash or Fish shell?

Tags: json, partitioning, jq, filesplitting

I have been using the wonderful [JQ library](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse and extract JSON data to facilitate re-importing.  I am able to extract a range easily enough, but am unsure as to how you could loop through in a script and detect the end of the file, preferably in a bash or fish shell script.

Given a JSON file that is wrapped in a *"results"* dictionary, how can I detect the end of the file?

From testing, I can see that I will get an empty array nested in my desired structure, but how can you detect the end of file condition?:

```
jq '{ "results": .results[0:500] }' Foo.json > 0000-0500/Foo.json
```

Thanks!

Comment: JSON doesn't deal with files, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: This is neither a bash nor fish question, so I removed those tags.

Comment: @chepner The point is that content is JSON, and I need to split in atomic json elements, preferably with bash or fish, and hence the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using jq to split-up the array into a stream of the JSON objects you want (one per line), and then using some other tool (e.g. awk) to populate the files.  Here's how the first part can be done:

```
def splitup(n):
  def _split:
    if length == 0 then empty
    else .[0:n], (.[n:] | _split)
    end;
  if n == 0 then empty elif n > 0 then _split else reverse|splitup(-n) end;

# For the sake of illustration:
def data: { results: [range(0,20)]};

data | .results | {results: splitup(5) }
```

Invocation:

```
$ jq -nc -f splitup.jq
{"results":[0,1,2,3,4]}
{"results":[5,6,7,8,9]}
{"results":[10,11,12,13,14]}
{"results":[15,16,17,18,19]}
```

For the second part, you could (for example) pipe the jq output to:

```
  awk '{ file="file."++n; print > file; close(file); }'
```

A variant you might be interested in would have the jq filter emit both the filename and the JSON on alternate lines; the awk script would then read the filename as well.