# Pandas Dataframe to JSON: returns a single line for 1 million records

Tags: json, data-science, jq, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I need to do some processing on my JSON data but it turn outs that my JSON is formatted in a way that it contains only one row. On Terminal, `wc -l file.json` is returning `0`

File is created converting Pandas Dataframe to JSON.

Here is the sample: `file.json`

```
[
{"id":683156,"overall_rating":5.0,"hotel_id":220216,"hotel_name":"Beacon Hill Hotel","title":"\u201cgreat hotel, great location\u201d","text":"The rooms here are not palatial","author_id":"C0F"},
{"id":692745,"overall_rating":5.0,"hotel_id":113317,"hotel_name":"Casablanca Hotel Times Square","title":"\u201cabsolutely delightful\u201d","text":"I travelled from Spain...","author_id":"8C1"}
]
```

Comment: Your sample is more than 1 row

Comment: What is your `jq` requirement for the problem stated? seems unclear

Comment: If I run wc -l file.json its returning 0. It should tell me that there are million rows. Why I need the number of rows? Because my data is large. I want to split it say 10,000 records per file. I can split the files using Unix Split command. For feeding the data to Split, my data should have multiple rows. @ΔO'deltazero'

Comment: @Inian this is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62609271/2533173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to split it say 10,000 records per file.

You could use jq to emit the top-level items in the array, one per line, as follows:

```
jq -c '.[]' file.json
```

If you simply want to partition this stream (without reconstituting each partition as an array), you can use a tool such as `split`.

If you want each partition to be an array, you could use jq to form the partitions, and then use a tool such as `awk` to create the separate files.  See for example this SO Q&A:
[Splitting / chunking JSON files with JQ in Bash or Fish shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881458/splitting-chunking-json-files-with-jq-in-bash-or-fish-shell)

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't need any whitespace, it's perfectly all right to store long JSON data without a single line break (therefore `wc -l` gives `0`).

If you want to "pretty print" you JSON in shell interface, use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
cat example.json
> [{"id":683156,"hotel_id":220216,"hotel_name":"Beacon Hill Hotel"},{"id":692745,"hotel_id":113317,"hotel_name":"Casablanca Hotel Times Square"}]

cat example.json | jq
> [
>   {
>     "id": 683156,
>     "hotel_id": 220216,
>     "hotel_name": "Beacon Hill Hotel"
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 692745,
>     "hotel_id": 113317,
>     "hotel_name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square"
>   }
> ]
```

For reporting length of an array, use `jq length`

```
cat example.json | jq length
> 2
```

Comment: This solution doesn't create one row per record, rather this solution creates a separate row for "id", another row for "hotel_id", another for "hotel_name".

Comment: This should show me 1 row for the whole object:
{
>     "id": 683156,
>     "hotel_id": 220216,
>     "hotel_name": "Beacon Hill Hotel"
>   }

Comment: I don't think having 1 array item per 1 file row (esp. when that item is a structured object) makes any sense in `JSON`

Comment: Right... Well my actual problem is this, could you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62609271/2533173

Comment: See my answer there, using `jq` to split the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's also an alternative (to proposed) solution, using [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) tool.

1. If your records do not contain any nested objects/arrays, like in the shown example, then a simple way to achieve it would be:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -t0c
[
{ "author_id": "C0F", "hotel_id": 220216, "hotel_name": "Beacon Hill Hotel", "id": 683156, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "The rooms here are not palatial", "title": "\u201cgreat hotel, great location\u201d" },
{ "author_id": "8C1", "hotel_id": 113317, "hotel_name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square", "id": 692745, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "I travelled from Spain...", "title": "\u201cabsolutely delightful\u201d" }
]
bash $
```

2. Otherwise (if they do), then a bit more complex solution with `sed` post-processing of the output is this:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -rw[:-1] -T'">{{}}<,"' -w[-1:] -TT -qq | sed '1s/^/[\
/; $s/$/\
]/'
[
{ "author_id": "C0F", "hotel_id": 220216, "hotel_name": "Beacon Hill Hotel", "id": 683156, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "The rooms here are not palatial", "title": "\u201cgreat hotel, great location\u201d" },
{ "author_id": "8C1", "hotel_id": 113317, "hotel_name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square", "id": 692745, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "I travelled from Spain...", "title": "\u201cabsolutely delightful\u201d" }
]
bash $
```

3. to display each record just on every line, it's then like this (but unsure if that's what you're after):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -rw[:] 
{ "author_id": "C0F", "hotel_id": 220216, "hotel_name": "Beacon Hill Hotel", "id": 683156, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "The rooms here are not palatial", "title": "\u201cgreat hotel, great location\u201d" }
{ "author_id": "8C1", "hotel_id": 113317, "hotel_name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square", "id": 692745, "overall_rating": 5.0, "text": "I travelled from Spain...", "title": "\u201cabsolutely delightful\u201d" }
bash $
```

PS. I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool. The disclaimer is required by the SO rules.